# Cannot resolve method not espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm using Espresso to test the view in the android. I want to make sure a text is not visible, but the "not" function is not working:

This does work to check if the text matches:

```java
onView(withId(R.id.detailTitle)).check(matches(withText("This is the title " + number)));
```

But I want to make sure the text does not match:

```java
onView(withId(R.id.detailTitle)).check(matches(not(withText(number))));
```

Then I get `Cannot resolve method not`

This is part of my gradle file:

```
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'

    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

May be Hamcrest helps you: testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'. We used 'not' from this library.

*.check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));*